# Menu Missing in IE9

Tags: javascript, menu, internet-explorer-9

The main menu is missing from the site in IE9 for some reason, and quite honestly not sure why. It works fine in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and IE9 "compatibility" mode.

http://www.logicweb.com/

Only chat button remains there.

Comment: What version of cufon are you using? [According to cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/), 1.09 is IE9-incompatible. Have you upgraded to 1.09i?

Comment: As @sdleihssirhc notes, it isn't compatible with 1.09 (but they supply a fix if you insist on using it): https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/faq#wiki-faq-8

Answer (score 0):

Comment out line 2 of /code/js/cufon.js and the menu reappears.

```
// Cufon.replace('#header > ul > li > a', { hover: true });
```